# Installing the Google Client Library for Python

Tags: python, shared-libraries, google-api-python-client

At https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-python it says to use `easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client` to install the library. In the video they use:

```
dhcp-172-19-39-181:gdl ccherubino$ sudo easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

neither of them work for me I get a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" [the : after 181 is supposedly invalid].

I have the easy_install tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

That's just their prompt. You type in the bit after `$`. But you do it from the shell, not from Python.

Comment: I tried "sudo easy_install..." but "easy_install" is an invalid syntax.